# Genexus WebPanel Variable de tipo HTML Gx X Ev3 U5

Tags: html, genexus

Estoy creando un Web Panel, donde necesito tener una variable de control Texto con Formato HTML, cosa que me funciona perfectamente en Transacciones, solo que en Web Panel no me funciona (muestra el html como texto).

1. Probé usar un dominio que ya tiene el formato en HTML, pero no funcionó.
2. Probé hacer la variable con tipo varchar(1000) y cambiar el formato en la misma, pero no funcionó.
3. Intenté modificar el formato en el Web Panel, pero el mismo aparece deshabilitado para cambiar.

Como se puede configurar para hacer esto o de que manera se puede hacer?

Gracias, Ariel

Answer (score 2):

Parece que a diferencia que en transacciones, en Web Panels hay que decirle que la variable es ReadOnly para poder modificar el formato, con eso pude ponerle el formato HTML y funcionó correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Ariel,

Si, pues el html es un modo de visualizacion, no de edicion (salvo si lo use el modo fckeditor)...